# How to resize div height to match sibling img height without fixed parent height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a scrollable bootstrap list-group that resizes as a sibling image is resized. The parent container doesn't have a fixed height and I can't use jQuery. Any thoughts?

https://jsfiddle.net/lgants/oL0rgsqk/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="row carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel-image-container">
      <img class="carousel-image img-responsive" src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=4">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-list-container">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
            <small>3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
            <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">List group item heading</h5>
            <small class="text-muted">3 days ago</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          <small class="text-muted">Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel {
  max-height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-image-container {
  width: 60%;
}

.carousel-image {
  max-width:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.carousel-list-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: can you specify classnames? which parent should be equal to which image?

Comment: @godblessstrawberry I can specify classnames. also, the height of the scrollable list group should be the same height as the adjacent image (i.e. size is dependent on the image and the parent is just a wrapper).

Comment: I mean can you tell me classnames - what is the exact parent that should be equal to the image? I'm not getting what you're trying to achieve. also you will need jQuery as its bootstrap dependency - `all JavaScript plugins require jQuery to be included` (c) http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download

Comment: @godblessstrawberry sorry; looks like the HTML didn't format properly; I've updated it and hopefully that will make things more clear. Otherwise, I'm afraid idk what other classnames you want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a cool trick involving percentage padding in CSS, since...

> The size of the padding as a percentage, relative to the width of the containing block. Must be nonnegative.

[MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

You can use this to your advantage to create truly responsive web layouts.

Here's the working [JSFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/oL0rgsqk/4/)

Here's the CSS I used:

```
.carousel-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.carousel-image-container {
  width: 60%;
  padding-top: 60%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel-list-container {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 60%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.carousel-list-container-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As well as adding an extra .carousel-list-container-scroll div around your .list-groups to enable scrolling in this setup

Comment: That's a very cool approach. Unfortunately, the image is getting cropped (i.e. it's not being resized with a consistent aspect ratio as the window is resized)

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you CAN do it otherwise without using JS.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to keep all your images the exact same ratio and update the width of each of the two sibling containers to match.